# Compute the distance d from y to the straight line through u and the origin.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let y =
$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and u = $$\begin{bmatrix} 8 \\6 \end{bmatrix}$$.
Compute the distance **d** from **y** to the straight line through **u** and the origin.

d = $$\begin{vmatrix} y - \frac{y * u}{u^2} u\end{vmatrix}$$
= $$\begin{vmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} - \frac{3(8)+1(6)}{8^2+6^2} \begin{bmatrix} 8 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix}\end{vmatrix}$$
= $$\begin{vmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} - \frac{30}{100} \begin{bmatrix} 8 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix}\end{vmatrix}$$
= $$\begin{vmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} \frac{24}{10}, \frac{18}{10}  \end{bmatrix} \end{vmatrix}$$

I don't know how to continue from here.
Could I get any tip on how to proceed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your background?

Comment: You're doing well so far, and you can just keep going, though I'm not quite sure what's tripping you up. Is it the fact that you're trying to subtract a row vector from a column vector? If so, then I'll point out that the row vector should actually be a column vector. Do you have trouble subtracting vectors? Or perhaps subtracting fractions like $\frac{24}{10}$ from integers like $3$? We can help out, but it would be good to get some idea of what is holding you up.

Comment: Damn this comment made me wish there was an option allowng one to upvote a comment more than 10 times @TheoBendit

Comment: Thanks @EthakkaappamwithChai. :)

Comment: @TheoBendit I was confused on how to subtract the column vector to the row vector. But after you have pointed out, the row vector should actually be a row vector. Now, do I just subtract fractions?

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai do I have to justify my background to ask help? Isn't it obvious enough that I'm asking this because I don't know. Or do you just want to judge me?

Comment: @Sampaguita I think you mean, the row vector should actually be a column vector. So now you just subtract the vectors componentwise, i.e. $\begin{bmatrix}3 - \frac{24}{10}\\1-\frac{18}{10}\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: = $$\begin{vmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} {\frac{3}{5}} \\ {-\frac{4}{5}} \end{bmatrix} \end{vmatrix}$$
= $$\sqrt {\begin{pmatrix} \frac{3}{5} \end{pmatrix} ^2 + \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{4}{5} \end{pmatrix}^2}$$
= $$\sqrt {\begin{pmatrix} \frac{9}{25} \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{16}{25} \end{pmatrix}}$$
= $$\sqrt \frac{9+16}{25} $$
= $$\sqrt 1 $$
= 1 
Is this right @TheoBendit?

Comment: @Sampaguita That's right. The answer confirms this too, by another method.

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The line through $u$ and the origin is given by $6x-8y=0$. Now the formula of the distance from a point $y=(y_1,y_2)$ to the line $ax+by+c=0$ is given by
$$\frac{|ay_1-by_2+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{18-8}{10}=1$$